# Being able to access LAN while using VPN

Tags: vpn, chromecast, openvpn, lan

On *Ubuntu*, using *network-manager*, I am able to acces my **local LAN** while at the same time using a **VPN** to access internet.

On *android* 4.4.4, I am using the app of my VPN provider (*PIA*), and there is no route to the local LAN when the VPN connexion is active.
The official *openVPN* app seems to behave the same way, although I don't recall clearly my test when using it.

Using a **non rooted** android, possibly reverting back to *openVPN app*, will I be able to cast to my *chromecast* while using my VPN ? how ?